# Get previously checked Radio Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, radio-button

Given a set of radio buttons, like:

```
<input id="B_1" type="radio" name="radioName" value="1">
<input id="B_2" type="radio" name="radioName" value="2">
<input id="B_3" type="radio" name="radioName" value="3">
<input id="B_4" type="radio" name="radioName" value="4">
```

**​When one of them gets checked is it possible to know which was previously active (if there is one)?**

I tried to attach the following function to the `onclick` event, but it doesn't work because it returns the the presently selected radio button instead of the one that was selected before:

```
my_func = function() {
    var checkedValue = $('input[type=radio]:checked').val();
    return alert("The previously selected was: " + checkedValue);
  };
```

I don't know if could be of any help, anyway here's the complete attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/H6h4R/

Comment: You have to rethink here. Everytime you click on a new radio - the checkValue just fills with the one you clicks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/H6h4R/1/

```
$(":radio").on("mousedown", function() {
    $("p").text( $('input[type=radio]:checked').val() );
}).on("mouseup", function() {
    $('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', false);
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

The `click` event is only triggered after this exact series of events:

- The mouse button is depressed while the pointer is inside the element.
- The mouse button is released while the pointer is inside the element.

Comment: Interesting! With the `mouse*` event it's now possible to access the button situation before changing the selection :) Though, clicking on the label doesn't work anymore.. I'll later need to customize the buttons look could that be a problem?

Comment: nope, it shouldn't be a problem.. But you have to attach the same listeners to your labels as well to make it work - http://jsfiddle.net/H6h4R/2/

Comment: Great! Thank you very much for the examples and the explanation, you really helped me!

Answer (score 0):

if he uses keyboard key this can help with that

http://jsfiddle.net/DYrW3/73/

```
$('input[name=radios]').keydown(function(){
        alert("Before change "+$('input[name=radios]:checked').val());
})
```