# Restoring value of previously checked radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I am working on a simple quiz application and now I added a Back button to it, allowing the user to go back and change his answer. For the already answered questions I want to show the radio button selected. I found one answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591335/get-previously-checked-radio-button), but it doesn't work for me.

Here's my HTML:

```html
<h1>Choose one of the following answers:</h1>


<h2 id="question">Question</h2>

<div id="form">
  <input type="radio" name="Answer" value="0">
  <label for="a1" id="a1">Answer 1</label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="Answer" value="1">
  <label for="a2" id="a2">Answer 2</label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="Answer" value="2">
  <label for="a3" id="a3">Answer 3</label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="Answer" value="3">
  <label for="a4" id="a4">Answer 4</label>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Back" id="prev" class="button">
  <input type="button" value="Next" id="next" class="button">
</div>
```

First I thought to store value of a previously checked radio button in a separate array, but that proved to be too troublesome. So I was wondering if there's a simple way to accomplish that with JS or jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone is interested, I decided to create a separate property in my `questions` object after all:

```js
questions.forEach(function (indx) { 
            indx.usersAnswer = null;
        });
```

Then I retrieve its value and set the corresponding radio button as checked:

```js
var showPrev = function () {
            var j = questions[numQuestion].usersAnswer;
            $('input[type="radio"][value="' + j + '"]').prop('checked', true);
        };
```

Probably not the best solution, but worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps and I think it will work out.

http://hibbard.eu/how-to-persist-checkbox-checked-state-after-page-reload/

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'm looking for something that doesn't involve using cookies..